# error with dfidx: the two indexes don't define unique observations

Tags: r, dataframe, mlogit

I have collected data from a survey in order to perform a choice based conjoint analysis.
I have preprocessed and clean data with python in order to use them in R.
However, when I apply the function dfidx on the dataset I get the following error:  the two indexes don't define unique observations.
I really do not understand why. Before creating the .csv file I checked if there were duplicates through the pandas function `final_df.duplicated().sum()` and its out put was 0 meaning that there were no duplicates.
Can please some one help me to understand what I am doing wrong ?

Here is the code:

```
df <- read.csv('.../survey_results.csv')
df <-  df[,-c(1)]
df$Platform <- as.factor(df$Platform)
df$Deposit <-  as.factor(df$Deposit)
df$Fees <-  as.factor(df$Fees)
df$Financial_Instrument <-  as.factor(df$Financial_Instrument)
df$Leverage <-  as.factor(df$Leverage)
df$Social_Trading <-  as.factor(df$Social_Trading)
df.mlogit <- dfidx(df, idx = list(c("resp.id","ques"), "position"), shape='long')
```

Here is the link to the dataset that I am using https://github.com/AlbertoDeBenedittis/conjoint-survey-shiny/blob/main/survey_results.csv

Thank you in advance for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `dfidx()` is build for data frames "for which observations are defined by two (potentialy nested) indexes" ([ref](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dfidx/dfidx.pdf)).

I don't think this function is build for more than two `idx`s. Especially that, in your df, there aren't any duplicates ONLY when considering the combinations of the three columns you mention above (`resp.id`, `ques` and `position`).

One solution to this problem is to "combine" the two columns `resp.id` and `ques` into one (called for example `resp.id.ques`) with `paste(...)`.

```
df$resp.id.ques <- paste(df$resp.id, df$ques, sep="_")
```

Then you can write the following line which should work just fine:

```
df.mlogit <- dfidx(df, idx = list("resp.id.ques", "position"))
```